# forecasting with multiple features using ARIMA

Tags: data-science, forecasting, arima

I have a problem where I want to forecast one value but I have multiple time series feature but target will be one of the feature. I have a tried ARIMA with single time series. Is there a way we can forecast with multiple input time series feature and single time series value as forecast-ed output?

Answer (score 2):

You can add exogenous features in ARIMA. That's what the "X" means in "SARIMAX". I don't know what programming language you are using, but you can do that in both Python/statsmodels and R. See https://otexts.com/fpp3/regarima.html

Comment: Yaa..Thanks for responding. I am using python and statmodels for ARIMA. The problem I am facing with exogenous is that I dont understand what to add as exogenous while forecasting...Because all exogenous values will be future value...I can add while training..but while forecasting I will not have those values.

Comment: You need to forecast them as well. You can use external sources for forecasts (like the Fed Survey of Professional forecasters for macro data like GDP, CPI). You can also use lagged values of the exogenous variables.

Comment: @RahulMisal In this case, you cannot use the standard implementations of ARIMA. For multivariate data, they are more nowcasters than forecasters because they assume you have the exogenous data at the future time points. You could use univariate models or other approaches like windowing and regression.

Comment: @GesoChisku  Thanks for your valuable inputs. I will explore other approaches like forecasting with LSTM dnn model.

Comment: @mloning Thanks for your valuable inputs. I will explore other approaches like forecasting with LSTM dnn model.